# VB.NET - Alias to class' properties

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop, class, object

I have an object and I iterate over object's properties. Foreach property, i append it as a column to a listview.

In my object, some properties doesn't have accents. But in portuguese, they do. For example: "Endereco" property must be "Endereço".

I need an away to create an alias to the properties. Is it possible in VB.NET?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like job for [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx).  You can use an attribute to decorate your properties with the exact header information you want.  For example:

```
<Description("Endereço")> _
Public Property String Endereco ....
```

And then use reflection to pull that value out in code.  You can also use the attribute value as a key into a localization table, to make future translation to other languages easier as well, or use other attributes to do things like tell your view not so show a particular field in certain circumstances.

---

To answer your reflection question, I'm assuming you're already at least a little comfortable with it, as that's how you have to iterate over an object's properties (unless what you really have is a dictionary, in which case you should have said so).  So as you're iterating over the properties the objects you're working with are of type [`PropertyInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z852kf5.aspx), and you can call the [`GetCustomAttributes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kff8s254.aspx) method for that type to find any attributes associated with the property.

Comment: Do you have the code for the Reflection? Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh, and this will spit out an IEnumerable list of KeyValuePair objects for a given class with property name and values:

    public Shared Function GetPropertyValueList(ByVal obj As Object) As IEnumerable(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))
        Return From p In obj.GetType().GetProperties() Select New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(p.Name, p.GetValue(obj, Nothing).ToString())
    End Function